# Check if an OpenCV Matrix is of floating point component type

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I want to test at runtime if a `cv::Mat` has floating point component type, i.e. if its type is one of `CV_32Fxx` and `CV_64Fxx`. I can do this with `if (mat.type() % 8 >= 5) {/*...*/}`, but this looks unexpressive and potentially wrong if OpenCV undergoes further development.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Does [Mat::depth()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-depth) not do the job?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. I was simply searching for the wrong words like 'component type', 'component size', 'bits per component', 'bits per channel', 'channel type', ... I was going mad. Please put it into an answer. I will accept it then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is OpenCV's [Mat::depth()](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-depth), which reports the element's "depth": Either `CV_8U`, `CV_8S`, `CV_16U`, `CV_16S`, `CV_32S`, `CV_32F` or `CV_64F`. You can just compare against the last two for your purposes.